# Como chamar um método dentro da classe?

Tags: c++, método

Estou tentando chamar o método que retorna um `unsigned char` através de outro método da mesma classe, revirei a internet toda mas não entendi como fazer isso.

```
byte CryrazCore::*ComputeByteArray(byte inputData[], bool decryptMode)
{
    int cs = this->CryrazCore::PushChecksum();
}
```

O método que estou tentando chamar se chama `CryrazCore::PushChecksum()`, eis a declaração dele:

```
// CryrazCore.cpp
byte CryrazCore::PushChecksum()
// CryrazCore.h
byte PushChecksum();
```

Aqui é o que diz no erro, na linha do primeiro código da pergunta.

> *'this': can only be referenced inside non-static member functions or non-static data member initializers*

Onde estou errando para chamar a função?

Comment: O que seria esse asterisco em `::*`? Se fosse para tornar um ponteiro para `byte` ele não deveria estar junto ao tipo? E se o retorno do método é `byte`, por quê a variável `cs` é do tipo `int`?

Comment: Como disse, sou novo. Não sei de quase nada nessa linguagem, coloquei o `::*` com esperança de ser uma chamada "estática", mas acho que tá tudo errado kkk

Comment: O ponteiro `*byte` seria mesma coisa de `ref byte` em C#, não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código nem compila por outros motivos também. Provavelmente ele seria assim:

```
byte *CryrazCore::ComputeByteArray(byte inputData[], bool decryptMode) {
    int cs = this->PushChecksum();
    //deveria usar os parâmetros
    return alguma coisa que seja um ponteiro para byte;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/CallIntanceMethod.cpp).

Tem que decidir se usa `this->` ou `CryrazCore::`, ambos não dá. O primeiro chama a instância, que parece ser o caso, o segundo chama um membro estático.

Procure fazer exemplos mais simples antes de começar fazer os mais complexos.

Comment: O retorno de `PushChecksum` é do tipo `byte`, mas `cs` está como `int`. Esse *cast* seria possível? Se sim, seria porquê o tipo `byte` é menor que `int` ou uso não tem relação?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o retorno é `byte*`, o *cast* é possível, falando de forma geral, C/C++ tem uma especificação complicada para atender todas arquiteturas, mas improvável que seja essa a intenção. O resto ficou sem sentido porque você partiu de uma informação errada. É possível porque na prática um ponteiro geralmente pode ser representado por `int`, embora não valha para todas arquiteturas. O código todo está muito errado e faz pouco sentido.

Comment: O método `ComputeByteArray` retorna o ponteiro, mas `PushChecksum` parece que não. Corrija-me se eu estiver errado, por favor.

Comment: Isso, e qual o problema?

Comment: Não sei. É que questionei se o retorno byte poderia ser armazenado no int sem problemas. Você disse que sim, porque geralmente o ponteiro pode ser armazenado no int, mas o retorno é por valor, não um ponteiro. Isso não influencia?

Comment: Isso eu nem sei dizer porque não conheço o tipo `byte` iso deve ser uma definição do código, não faz parte do C++. O retorno deve ser um ponteiro, ele deve ter colocado o ponteiro no lugar errado, geralmente é um ponteiro. Eu imagino que esse `byte` na verdade seja um `char` internamente, e é raro retornar isso. Se nada disso for verdade, o AP tem que dizer. Só ele entende esse código, eu dei a solução para o problema específico, todos os outros problemas depende do que é o código real, esse exige especulação para corrigir. Até tentei. Por isso que eu disse que nem compila por outros motivos.

Comment: O tipo byte é um `using byte = unsigned char;`.